# How to read & write 1 byte into a particular memory address?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to read a single byte from a particular memory address of a structure followed by writing that same byte into that same address. My goal is to load 64-byte memory associated with that memory address into the cache line.

I have a structure variable `testStructure` of size `12584`. I tried the following code to read and write back 1 byte into the memory address,

```
unsigned char *p;
int forEachCacheLine = sizeof(testStructure);
printf("size of forEachCacheLine is %d\n", forEachCacheLine);

for (int i = 0; i<forEachCacheLine ; i+=64) {

    printf("i is %d\n",i);

    // read 1 byte 
    p=(unsigned char *)&testStructure+i;
    printf("Read from %p byte is %hhx\n", &testStructure+i, p);


    // write 1 byte
    *(unsigned char *)(&testStructure+i)=p;
    printf("Write into %p byte is %hhx\n\n", &testStructure+i, p);
}
```

upon running the code I get the following output:

```
size of forEachCacheLine is 12584
i is 0  
Read from 0x7f5d42e71f80 byte is 80
Write into 0x7f5d42e71f80 byte is 80

i is 64  
Read from 0x7f5d42f36980 byte is c0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As the output shows, the writing attempt in the first iteration was successful. However, the second iteration causes a `Segfault`. Any comments on why I'm getting this `Segmentation fault`?

I'm not quite sure if this is the correct approach to achieve my goal. But as of now, this is the only way I can think off. If this is an incorrect approach can someone please suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: After `p=(unsigned char *)&testStructure+i;`, `p` is the same than `&testStructure+i`, so you can do `printf("Read from %p byte is %hhx\n", p, p);`.

Comment: I'd add extra parenthesis in pointer assigment, even if not needed. For example, use `p = (&testStructure) + i;`.

Comment: Be careful with pointer arithmetic. `(&testStructure+i)` does not add `i` to the address, but `i * sizeof testStructure`

Comment: In the write assignment `*(unsigned char *)(&testStructure+i)=p;`: `p` is not a byte, is a pointer to a byte. If you'd like to write the value pointed by this pointer, you should do `(&testStructure) + i = *p;`. But, if this worked, it should write the same byte, because `p` is pointing to the same memory address as `(&testStructure) + i` due the the previous assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your for loop only seems to increment `i` by 64 bytes each iteration, your debug output shows that the second read is 805376 bytes beyond the first - which is out of bounds and likely causing the segfault. 805376 is 64 times 12584. What this means is that each iteration is incrementing p by 64 `teststructure`'s instead of 64 `chars`.

Try replacing

```
p=(unsigned char *)&testStructure+i;
```

with

```
p=((unsigned char *)&testStructure)+i;
```

This ensures that `&teststructure` is a `char*` and not a `teststructure*` when we add `i` to it.

On most modern systems, there is little to no performance gain from explicitly caching memory like this. If you really want the memory in cache though - try using `__builtin_prefetch()` on each 64 bytes of `teststructure`. This is a GNU extension that populates a cache line. You should also pay attention to it's optional arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the example code. @Weather Vane points out the same problem that you've mentioned. I was still struggling to fix that. Your example code helps me. So, finally for 1-byte reading my code looks like `p=((unsigned char *)&cacheCryptoEnv)+i;` and for writing 1-byte `*(((unsigned char *)&cacheCryptoEnv)+i)=*p;`. I'm getting the desired output I was aiming for.